# ajax calling javascript with parameters and get response, node-webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, node-webkit

This is kind of confusing. I need this because i am using **node.js (node-webkit)** in local, there is no php to wait for a response. Just javascript code and files.

I want to do an ajax call with parameters (i did not think yet about get or post parameters) to a "url" of a javascript file.

I do not want the .js code, i want to call it like a .php, waiting for a response (that is actually a json response format)

Jquery has .getScript which copies all the code and run it, but i can't send parameters, and i can't load the whole file everytime i need the response.

It is hard to explain this so i make an example.

This is an Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({    
  url: 'test.php',
  data:"infotosend="+info,
  type: 'POST',
success: function (resp) {     
  if(resp){
     console.log(resp);
  }
```

PHP:

```
$_GET or $_POST (get the parameters)
Create answer
Respond answer
```

**I want the same behaviour, but calling .js files**, where i catch the get or post parameters (dont know also how yet), make some proccess and give a json answer.

I hope i explained myself, and if this is not possible, give me some advice to do asynchronous calls with parameters.

Comment: Just add the .js files to the same page and call the functions like normal.

Comment: In this case im using a third party API for big tables which force me to use ajax function to reduce lag. Avoiding this would make the app in the future really slow. And using my own code implementing the function inside makes the API totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

With Node.js, JavaScript files make up your backend - essentially replacing the PHP that you're used to. Don't think of it as "calling .js files", it's just a different way to do what you're used to doing with PHP. You should probably take a look at the `express` framework, which is a framework for developing a node backend for processing requests and returning results (REST). The first example on the express documentation shows you how to define a GET request endpoint.

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

Comment: Express is very useful for web aplications, but i am working with "node-webkit" for a standalone desktop app. I can use it anyway, but most of the features become useless in local mode, and i have to change some routes to prevent foreign connection, ...